# tfs 2015 portfolio backlog and source control

Tags: tfs, backlog

We recently upgraded to tfs 2015. One of the features I'd like to implement is portfolio backlogs. We have a group of 7 developers split between 2 teams with a product manager for each team.

I like the idea of a top level or "master" backlog where I can create epics and features as the IT Director, and let the product managers manage their own backlogs based on the priority of the epics/features.

I configured portfolio backlogs using this [guidance](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/work/scale/portfolio-management). For example we have a top level project called 'company' and areas under this project like 'company / web stores' and 'company / CRM'

In the past we setup a project whenever we wanted a new source code repository. So we have 7 existing TFS projects.

My question is how do we setup source code repositories to support our existing 7 projects with portfolio backlogs?

```
Current structure:
Project 1 (backlog + source code)
Project 2 (backlog + source code)
Project 3 (backlog + source code)

Desired structure:
Company Backlog (Epics & Features)
-Team1 (PBIs + source code)
-Team2 (PBIs + source code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is potentially a huge question.

You want to have one team project subdivided into various teams, which is normal and a good practice. However, if you're using TFVC, you can only have one TFVC repository per team project. In that case, you'd have all your source code in the same TFVC repository subdivided into different folders. You can control access to source code on a folder-by-folder basis depending on team.

If you're using Git, just put each project into its own repository and you're good to go.

Comment: So the simpler option to support this structure is to use Git. Any reason not to move from TFVC to Git?

Comment: @Pattison Git uses a drastically different version control paradigm with a significant learning curve. If the team is unfamiliar with it and is currently working happily with TFVC, switching to Git may represent an unwelcome and highly disruptive change.